# Flowtype nominal typing for primitive

Tags: javascript, string, flowtype

I'm looking for the best solution to separate the usage of strings as identifiers for translated messages and literal text values.

So i might have an object field called `title`, which in this case refers to the title of a form and it will have the value `SIGNUP_FORM_TITLE` or `MAIL_FORM_TITLE` so it will refer to a localized string and will be passed to a function like `format(id)` which returns the actual localized text for the current locale.

But then i might also have an object field `name` which refers to a person's name and is not localized, so it might have the value `John Doe`.

How can i make sure i get a type error when i pass name to format(id), and vice versa when i pass `title` to an API that expects a plain (text) string.

I can't (of course) just say `type LocalizationIdentifierType = string` as this is just an alias.

Maybe i could make a subclass of string `class LocalizationIdentifier extends String` but this would still allow `LocalizationIdentifier` to be passed to a string based API (or at least i think thats the case).

Has anyone a better idea to sort of nominally type a string?
Or maybe i'm completely on the wrong track? ("Auf dem Holzweg" as we say in Germany)

---

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810574/is-there-a-way-to-create-nominal-types-in-typescript-that-extend-primitive-types) and a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/364) to add similar functionality to typescript.
Choosing typescript over flowtype is, of course, not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for are Flow's [opaque type aliases](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/)

You could make an opaque type alias: 
`opaque type LocalizationIdentifierType = string`

This would behave as a string inside the file, but as a nominal type outside of the file.

You mention that you want something similar to `LocalizationIdentifierType extends String` -- you can achieve this by adding a subtyping constraint onto your opaque type alias:

`opaque type LocalizationIdentifierType: string = string`

This means that a `LocalizationIdentifierType` is a string, but not all strings are a `LocalizationIdentifierType`

Comment: yes indeed. I'm already using this, but it wasn't available when i asked this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Literal types almost work. You can specify the signature of `format` as

```
function format(id: "SIGNUP_FORM_TITLE" | "MAIL_FORM_TITLE" | ...): string {
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this falls apart for your other case (localized text wrongly passed to the plain text API). An object literal type seem like the JavaScript path of least resistance:

```
type LocalizedString = {
  +field: "SIGNUP_FORM_TITLE" | "MAIL_FORM_TITLE"
};
type PlainText = string;

const signupFormTitle: LocalizedString = { field: "SIGNUP_FORM_TITLE" };
const mailFormTitle: LocalizedString = { field: "MAIL_FORM_TITLE" };
```

If you need to introduce variations on `LocalizedString`, an additional tag field in the objects works nicely, e.g.:

```
type LocalizedString = {
  +variant: "variant1",
  +field: "SIGNUP_FORM_TITLE" | "MAIL_FORM_TITLE"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround unfortunately this didn't quite match what i was thinking about. I'm really glad, that opaque types made it now ☺️