# How can I secure my domain-driven types with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

To make sure I don't use variables in the wrong context, I would like to statically check my code with domain-driven types. Is it possible to make the compiler warn me about the usage of a translated string as an identifier in the context below?

```js
type Translated = string;
type Identifier = string;

function translate(key: Identifier): Translated {
  return `translated ${key}`;
}

const a: Identifier = "a.b.c";
const b: Translated = "hello";

const run = () => {
  const c = translate(b); // <- shouldn't this fail?
  console.log(c);
};

run();
```

Here is a [TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgQCZQLxQrBwCWSA5gNwCwAUKJFAJLYRLAkBmJEc+hxMlTp1OAVyQBjDgHskUYsnSYIACgDWEEAC5mrdlx5wAlLvhKMWXAG86UKHAjAxceQANFqSzigASa5ogAL5uNLRBIrSSckRQCLosbBzcvPwARAgAdABGmZJpYdGowFDZZoheKrgEaQAWEGhoMgWRRbFwEvyqxvgAfFC2tPZtJZL8nspYqtnGlFAA9PNQADwAtIS1MmJo2EgA5CXAtSQoUJwIJGgA-HZQbTJoEJlN5KqSs3RBYXQdSN1hQA) for the code above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create nominal types in TypeScript that extend primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810574/is-there-a-way-to-create-nominal-types-in-typescript-that-extend-primitive-types)

Comment: Someone posted a possible answer, which seems to be similar to the one I've just accepted. @AlekseyL. The question is quite misleading as it's trying to do something in a specific way and the accepted answer is "no" instead of one of the possible workarounds

Comment: Yeah, there're tons questions/answers with same workaround. The answer is still no and this is still duplicate 

Comment: I definitely see value in relating these issues as you learn a lot from its answers. Still I have to disagree: The linked question is about doing a very specific thing that would lead to a feasible workaround. If you are searching for a generic way to create type safety if you have the same basic structure, I doubt anyone would find the working workarounds in the non-accepted answers of a seemingly unrelated question - especially not knowing the keyword "nominal type system". If there is a more fitting question/answer, please link it as well and you can close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you are looking for ([It comes from this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/)) :

```
interface Flavoring<FlavorT> {
  _type?: FlavorT;
}
export type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;


type Translated = Flavor<string, 'Translated'>;
type Identifier = Flavor<string, 'Identifier'>;;

function translate(key: Identifier): Translated {
  return `translated ${key}`;
}

const a: Identifier = "a.b.c";
const b: Translated = "hello";

const run = () => {
  const c = translate(b); // <- Fails
  const d = translate(a); // <- OK
  console.log({c, d});
};
```

This flavoring can be use with numbers for Latitude, Longitude. Or for Ids : if you want `UserId` and `PostId` not to be possible to swap. Or anything you can think of... It is very convenient to avoid flipping types that would otherwise be the same.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand this correctly, the basic idea is to use a new type with a "tag", being the name of the type. It's not perfect, since `translate(a + b)` would work, but I think in most contexts this helps

Comment: Yes, it is just a typescript tag and it works most of the time. I encourage you to read the article.

Comment: Actually most of the time it won't work as expected. Even simple `b + b` will result in `string`

Comment: well, it is used to identify specific strings (or number), so you probably don't need to do such things on transations, or on Ids. If you do need that a lot, than you are right, it is probably not a good solution.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with this, actually. The translate and identifier was just a very simple example on what I was looking for. If you use functions for addition instead of operators, the Flavor typings help a lot. Could you provide examples where this causes problems @AlekseyL.? For example `translate(translate(someIdentifier))` fails as expected, so I don't really understand why you seem to dislike this approach...?

Comment: I don't seem to dislike this approach, I'm just saying that it is still workaround that works for very specific use cases