# How to create unassignable numbers in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In our country there are two currencies, rial and toman, which can be converted into each other (1 toman = 10 rial), I want to create a specific type for each currency, that to be unassignable.
**I don't want to lose any performance (for example by using objects instead of number)**

example code:

```
type toman = number
type rial = number

function x(r: rial): void {
   console.log(r)
}


const t: toman = 5
x(t) // I want to get an error here, because toman is unassignable to rial
```

Comment: You can't. *Encapsulate* the value instead, for example `class Toman { constructor(readonly value: number) {} }`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The idea also came to me, but it is not optimal in terms of performance

Comment: Then you'll have to decide which you prefer, but those are your choices. Please note that you should include what you've considered and dismissed and why *in your question*.

Comment: There is a similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810574/is-there-a-way-to-create-nominal-types-in-typescript-that-extend-primitive-types but as far as as read there is no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This one works, but it's not a pretty solution!

```
interface Toman {
   n: 'toman'
}

interface Rial {
   n: 'rial'
}

type toman = Toman | number
type rial = Rial | number

function x(r: rial): void {
   console.log(r)
}

const t = 5 as toman
x(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has [structural types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), so if you want two types to be unassignable to each other then they must have incompatible structures. We can achieve this by giving the types extra properties to distinguish them; these properties won't really exist at runtime, so there is no performance penalty.

Note that you need a type assertion like `5 as toman` at the place the value is assigned.

```
type toman = number & { __toman: toman }
type rial = number & { __rial: rial }

function x(r: rial): void {
   console.log(r)
}

const t = 5 as toman
x(t) // error: property '__rial' is missing
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMD2C2BDAdlAvFZBXeAjCATlAGRQDeUA+pXEsgFwwIpQC+AUKJFAQJaIAbdJhz4ipCtT6DG0oR3YAzLMgDGwXrFQAPABQFZ-AQEpGAN1i8AJuXZR7qrQGdYAiADoBsAOb7j7BUdkJ2AYYQBWKEQnJjp2PWBjKAB6ZKhCAlgDKDBMyAJQKAByKSMiqF4Y+EqnXmRvdiA)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason for it since both have the same type: numbers. However, you could do something like:

```
type Currency<PropertyName extends string> = {
    [key in PropertyName]: number
}

function x(r: Currency<'rial'>): void {
   console.log(r)
}


const t = {toman: 5} // change to { rial: 5 } to fix the ts error below
x(t) // You you get an error
```

Comment: Thanks, But as I said, I don't want to use objects instead of number