# How to specify the type of a function returning unique class?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns a new class every time, is class factory:

```
function foo() {
    const s = Symbol();
    return class {
        protected readonly s: typeof s = s;
    };
}

const c1 = foo();
const c2 = foo();

const cc: typeof c1 = c2; // Error expected

const i1 = new c1();
const i2 = new c2();

const ii: typeof i1 = i2; // Error expected
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIgxCBAZykRMQF5EBlATwFsAjOAG0wG59CAnAUygheSCGwCGJSnkKzEAB15wo-aPwAmiAePUI29CgC5EUevP5xgFahW6yAvt3u5cxMGSIBGGynQZubh4QAEw+qFwugeQQEMam5pZeNiGciAD0aYgAorxKvIj8AB7mauqRpOQw3jRg-ADuXhFRiDChNfVEwRGuFS0wcWYWVlU2rakZ2blw+UUlKmVAA)

But I can assign the class or instances of one invocation with another without error.

The [FAQ#When and why are classes nominal?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal) says that a class with protected or private memebers becomes *nominal* in the sense that their are not interchangeable (that is not exactly what it says, but that's the idea I think).

**Is there a way to type `foo` so TypeScript can detect that `typeof i1` isn't assignable to `typeof i2`?**

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199492/atomic-type-discrimination-nominal-atomic-types-in-typescript).  I don't know of any *programmatic* way to *generate* nominal types.  A function like `foo()` that spits out unique things every time it's called seems to be outside TypeScript's ability to describe, at least at first glance.  It's almost like we want [dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) or [existential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) types for this, but those aren't natively supported.  ‍♂️